# Having trouble installing matplotlib in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, conda

I tried updating conda, and I got this message:
`ERROR conda.core.link:_execute_actions(337): An error occurred while uninstalling package 'defaults::requests-2.14.2-py36_0'. PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')`.
And if I try updating just matplotlib on conda, I get: `ERROR conda.core.link:_execute_actions: An error occurred while installing package`

Answer (score 0):

The first question when you update conda is that `PermissionError`, maybe you just do not have enough system permission. The second question, you did not give enough error tips.

Comment: I shouldn't have a system problem, it's my personal laptop, not a work laptop with high security.